# How to create a trigger on after insert without returning NEW in postgres?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, triggers

Why do it after insertion? How write something like this:

```
    CREATE FUNCTION update_auto_dates() RETURNS trigger AS $update_auto_dates$
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dates (dates_user, dates_object, dates_object_id, dates_date) VALUES (NEW.user, NEW.object, NEW.object_id, NEW.date);
    END;
$update_auto_dates$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER update_auto_dates AFTER INSERT ON log
    FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_auto_dates();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The trigger function is required to return something](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/trigger-definition.html) because its definition does not define that it is used as an after trigger. That is only known in the trigger definition.

Adding a `RETURN NEW;` statement might be a good idea to prevent surprises when it is used (accidentally) as a BEFORE trigger in the future. You can also choose to `RETURN NULL;` as the result is ignored for AFTER triggers.

Comment: I hope you don't mind the link, as it answers well itself and will be tldr to your answer